# How to hide the vertical scroll bar of a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide the vertical scroll bar.

But the mouse wheel or keyboard are still available.

Comment: use `overflow:hidden`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: You can do this with CSS, no need for JS

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS of the element you want to hide the scrollbar from, use
`overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS `overflow:hidden` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

see this fiddle [`jsfiddle link`](http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/4/) this will help you for you purpose